# What would be a better performing DELETE query that runs often?

Tags: mysql

I'm currently using MySQL 5.5 via AWS RDS and node.js for the server. We have a couple web apps that use a central server and auth is token based that is kind of oauth like. When you login, you get an auth code and exchange it for an access and refresh token. Then at an interval, the refresh token is used to get a new access and refresh token. All three tokens have an expiry and currently when we create new tokens, we have a DELETE query that will delete expired tokens. Here is a sample of this:

```
DELETE FROM tokens WHERE expires <= NOW() LIMIT 50;
INSERT INTO tokens (type, ...) VALUES ('access', ...);
INSERT INTO tokens (type, ...) VALUES ('refresh', ...);
```

These 3 statements get sent as a single transaction to the db server, they are not queried individually. The tokens table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `tokens` (
  `type` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `system` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `userid` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `key` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `token` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `expires` datetime NOT NULL,
  `scopes` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`token`,`expires`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This has been working for a couple years and 99% of the time works great. Randomly, the server hangs and will not take any more connections or queries. Looking at the process list, there are a bunch of DELETE queries that are hanging. It seems the rows are locking since I have a WHERE and an INSERT is trying to execute and things get mangled. The DELETE is only picking 50 rows at max to delete so I'm curious as to why this would bork randomly?

We are trying to take other measures to work around this like delete a smaller chunk and less frequently (extend the access token expiration).

Is there a better way to go about this to clean up expired tokens?

Answer (score 1):

You should add an index on `expires`. The composite index `(token, expires)` can only be used for queries that search for both `token` and `expires` or `token` by itself (because it's a prefix of the composite index).

Then the `DELETE` query will be able to use that index, and won't lock all the other rows in the table that it scanned while looking for expired tokens.

Depending on other queries you do, it might work to just swap the order of the columns in your existing index, i.e. changing it to `PRIMARY KEY (expires, token)`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Removed the primary key and attempted to add expires back in and was caught by duplicate entries which makes some sense. So added token as primary and an index on expires. So it's now `PRIMARY KEY (token), KEY expires (expires)`. I won't really be able to tell if this works until it fails again.

Comment: Are you sure that primary is correct? The old schema would allow duplicate tokens with different expires, now you don't allow that any more. Was the old behavior intended or a mistake?

Comment: Having `PRIMARY KEY(token, expires)` was just adding expires on, truth be told I didn't know it creates a composite, thought it would just add both. Splitting them up is just my own ignorance and you saying "might" put me off. Having `PRIMARY KEY(expires, token)` doesn't mean a perf hit or locking? Splitting them wouldn't help any? I don't really have a good way to test this and it's all in production and issue is prod db keeps locking up once every couple weeks randomly.

Comment: I think you need to read some documentation on how multiple-column indexes work (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html). And remember that a primary key is also a *unique* index, so `PRIMARY KEY(token, expires)` means that the combination of the two columns has to be unique, but not either of them by themselves.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your replies.